# How to check if a permutation (or part) of a string is in list (dictionary)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I programming a simple search app for Scrabble. Find all possible words from a string.
Permutation part is done. I've created a function Permute(string) that output an array with all permutation.

```
var dictionary=["abc","abcd",ab","dhgd","adbft"];

var input="abcd";
    output=Permute(input);
    //result:
    0:"abcd"
    1:"abdc"
    2:"acbd"
    3:"acdb"
    4:"adbc"
    5:"adcb"
...etc
```

Now, I have to check if words exist. Should I try all length? Is there another more efficient way?

```
    //Check all the item of the output array
    for(var i=0; i<output.length;i++){
        //Check if all length of output
        for(var j=2;j<output[i].length;i++)
            //Check all these possibilities if they exist in the dictionary
            for(word in dictionary){
                output[i].substring[1:j]==dictionary[word];
}

    }};
```

I can't really imagine how long it would be if the dictionary is 250 000 words... Is there a better way?

Comment: How about documenting the length of each character occurrences and use that to match instead?

Comment: I don't understand. May you explain?

Comment: Build a hash for each dict entry that consists of the number of occurrences of each character. search the bucket. Thus you only have to search the bucket of a single hash entry (I think this is @DanielCheung's suggestion fleshed out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to check with anagrams is the length. If you dictionary is only for checking if the permutation exists then I would create a structure with length as a first dimension. e.g.

```
dictionary = {1: ['a', 'i'], ... 3: ['cat', 'dog', 'too']}
```

This is easy to do.

Next, permutations aren't the most efficient way to check for anagrams. You could, for example, sort the characters and them compare:

```
 dictionary = {1: ['a', 'i'], ... 3: ['act', 'dgo', 'oot']}
```

Then you can sort the characters your query string and do a direct comparison. This cuts out a huge chunk of permutations.

Then you should reconsider using a linear structure for your dictionary. Something hash-based works much better. Why not use the built-in dictionary in Javascript.

```
dictionary = {1: {'a': ['a'], 'i': ['i']}, ... 3: {'act': ['cat', 'cat'], 'dgo': ['dog'], 'oot': ['too']}}
```

This maps the sorted string to the possible strings that are anagrams.

Then to find your potential words you just look up `dictionary[myword.length][sort_string(myword)]`

Your sort function is:

```
function sort_string(input) {
    return input.split("").sort().join("")}
```

The resulting complexity will be O(1)ish (one step to calculate the length, one step to sort the letters, one step to look up first level, one step to hash and look up second level). It doesn't slow down as the dictionary increases.

Your original was O(n), i.e. searching the dictionary for as many words as exist, and the speed depends how big your dictionary is.

If you want to search for possible available words, then you're going to want to create ngrams and search for those. Decide what's the minimum word length and the maximum word length, then create windows of that length. This would require creating permutations and at this point you get into more interesting algorithms like search trees, back-tracking etc. I suggest a read of the relevant Wikipedia articles.

Comment: You could create a map with the sorted characters being the key and the potential words being the values. Then the final lookup would be even faster.

Comment: Huuuum! Good extra! But would it work if my input is "doga" (so "adgo"). It will not find "dog"?

Comment: Thanks for your help/time. I knew I was going the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to generate all permutations.  Instead, make your key your dictionary on *one* permutation of the letters.  The lexically smallest permuation is easiest -- just sort the letters in the keys.

So your dictionary becomes a map from a sorted string of letters to the anagrams of that string that are acutally words.  If `'god'` and `'dog'` are words, for example, then your dictionary will have an entry `'dgo' -> ['dog','god']`.

Then, to do a search, just sort all the letters in the input, and then check the dictionary for all subsequences of the resulting string.

If you have `'ogdb'`, the sorting produces `'bdgo'`, and you check the dictionary for `'b'`, `'d'`, `'g'`, `'o'`, `'bd'`, `'bg'`, `'bo'`, etc.  When you get to `'dgo'`, you'll find `'god'` and `'dog'` in the dictionary.

With 7 letters, there are 127 possible subsequences.  Checking a dictionary for 127 keys is quite fast.